# Prolog saying if something in a list (in this case grid/1) is white. Prolog

Tags: prolog, predicate, maze

I am new to prolog and wanted to know if you have a maze with certain ''pixels''. How could you implement a predicate white/1, which says if the pixel is a white one or a black one. The problem that I have is that I want to make a predicate, that if I query ?- white(3/3). it should return true. This is my database:

```
grid([ [w, w, w, b, w],
[b ,b, w, w, w],
[w, w, w, b, w],
[w, b, b, b, b],
[w, w, w, w, w] ]).
```

Thanks for the answer, I implemented this program:

```
white(X/Y) :-
    nth1(X/Y, grid, _).
```

But after implementing this program I still get a false.

Comment: Your problem boils down to finding `nth` element of a list. Look at `nth0` or `nth1` predicate. With two calls to it you can get the corresponding element. Then you can check if it is white

Comment: @rajashekar thanks for the suggestion, but I find it difficult to implement this predicate, as it seems to me that it has to have 2 different arguments instead of 1 as I have to define the given list vertically and horizontally.

Comment: @rajashekar Thank you for explaining it to me. I now understand what the built-in predicate nth1 does and how to implement it. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
white(X/Y) :-
    grid(M),
    nth1(X, M, Line),
    nth1(Y, Line, w).
```

The first `nth1` get the row, and the second one gets the element of the row.

I suggest playing with the query

```
?- grid(M), nth1(X, M, Line), nth1(Y, Line, Cell).

Cell = w
Line = [w,w,w,b,w]
M = [[w,w,w,b,w],[b,b,w,w,w],[w,w,w,b,w],[w,b,b,b,b],[w,w,w,w,w]]
X = 1
Y = 1 ? ;

Cell = w
Line = [w,w,w,b,w]
M = [[w,w,w,b,w],[b,b,w,w,w],[w,w,w,b,w],[w,b,b,b,b],[w,w,w,w,w]]
X = 1
Y = 2 ? ;

Cell = w
Line = [w,w,w,b,w]
M = [[w,w,w,b,w],[b,b,w,w,w],[w,w,w,b,w],[w,b,b,b,b],[w,w,w,w,w]]
X = 1
Y = 3 ? ;

Cell = b
Line = [w,w,w,b,w]
M = [[w,w,w,b,w],[b,b,w,w,w],[w,w,w,b,w],[w,b,b,b,b],[w,w,w,w,w]]
X = 1
Y = 4 ? ;
```

Just press `;` after each solution and prolog will iterate through every possible X, Y for your maze. You can get a feeling of how `nth1` is accessing the cell.

In general I would advise that you use two explicit parameters such as `white(X, Y)` unless there is a good reason to use `X/Y`.